# Why does our SiteCatalyst Searches report of shows 'N/A' values

Tags: adobe-analytics

Our company has a "Traffic Source" report that shows "Search Keyword - All" broken down by a conversion variable that "stacks" keywords from search engines using crossVisitParticipation and channelManager plugins/functions. The conversion variables  and the referring url are transmitted to Omniture correctly (I verified that by the SC Debugger).

The problem is that when we choose the "Searches" metric the values show "N/A". Why would this happen? Do we have something configured wrong?

Here is photo of our report:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1s2i.jpg

Here is a similar report with the keyword stack by pages. It has the same problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xLX5.jpg

Here is a javascript snip of code that sets the conversion var:

```
var o=s.channelManager(false);
if(typeof o != 'undefined' && o.keyword != 'n/a' && o) {
s.eVar24=s.crossVisitParticipation(o.keyword,'s_kw','90','9',' > ','event4,purchase,1'); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I should note that this happens from all search engines not just Google. I know there is a problem with people not signed into Google not passing the keywords.

Actually it happens from all search engines. Not only Google.

The problem looks a little like this post from Adam Greco. 

http://adam.webanalyticsdemystified.com/2009/08/13/custom-search-success-events/

I don't understand why "n/a" values are populating his report also.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is exactly what Adam Greco wrote up there.  The 'Searches' metric is the same as the instances metric.  Neither of which are subrelated, which means the metric relates only to the conversion variable it is set against.

So when you do a breakdown on your Search Keywords by the Keyword Stack the Searches metric doesn't apply to the Stack values on rows below - thus n/a, or 'not applicable'.

Try adding the Visits metric instead.